# Add release from non-tracked file with Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repo on Github for my nuget library. I would like to set it up so that when I merge to master from dev a new release will be created, containing my *.nupkg file.

However my *.nupkg files aren't being tracked and I'd like to keep it that way.

Can this be achieved with Github Actions or do I need another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create a script in your project that creates an appropriate file and invoke it as part of your GitHub Action workflow.  Many projects do something like this.

If your goal is to have the file magically created from nowhere without having any source content or script to create it within the repository, then I'd suggest looking for an existing action that does this for you.

If your concern is that the file may contain secrets or private information and you'd rather not include it literally, then you should use a script and use the GitHub Actions secrets functionality to read the secrets from the environment and pass them to the script.

Without knowing more about exactly what your concern is with including these files, it's hard to come up with a definitive solution that meets your needs.